# AJAX post - {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript but it is not working : I receive the following error : `{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`
This script is included in a webpage of my site which is in a subdirectory of the site.

From my debugging, I do not understand where the error can come from... (since I do quite exactly the same for the index webpage of my site with another javascript which looks almost the same)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //if submit button is clicked
    $('#filterbtn').click(function () {        

        //Get the data from all the fields
        var a = JSON.stringify( $("#multiselect").val() );
        var b;
        if ($('#b').prop('checked')) {
            b = 0;
        } else {
            b = 1;
        }
        var c = JSON.stringify($("#Sliderstart").slider("value"));
        var d = JSON.stringify($("#Sliderend").slider("value"));

        //organize the data properly
        var data = 'b=' + b + '&c=' + c + '&d=' + d + '&a=' + a;

        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "./filter.php", 
            type: "POST",         
            data: data, 
            crossDomain: true,  
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {                  
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=html;                              
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));
            }        
        });
        return false;
    });     
 });
```

Thank you guys !

Cheers

Comment: Why is crossdomain call set to true with a relative URL?

Comment: what do you mean by sub directory? Is it a subdomain? If so request is cross domain and subject to security policies

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of error you get when you request an url that doesn't exist.

Try changing this:

```
url: "./filter.php"
```

to an aboslute path like this:

```
url: "/PATH_TO_FILTER/filter.php"
```

Comment: Thank you all. It is fixed now.