# Intel XDK Ajax Access not allowed after uploading to server [working good in xampp]

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, intel-xdk

I am building an XDK app,
was working good in xampp and fixed the header problem, after uploading to a live server the ajax call is not working and I got this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://watanydemo.eb2a.com/metawe3/action/get?_=1451186106865. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
index.html:92 {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

Although I set the header by all the ways and still the origin is set to null

```
public function get()
{ $this->load->model('Name_model');  
$result = $this->Name_model->read_names();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo json_encode($result);
}
```

NB my back end is Codeigniter

my Ajax call is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

$('#loading-image').show();
            try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://watanydemo.eb2a.com/metawe3/action/get",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("valid response");

for (var i = 0, res = response.length; i < res; ++i) {
 var picture = response[i].picurl;
var name= response[i].name;


 $("#row").append('<div class="col-md-4"><h1>'+name+'</h1><img id="pic" class="thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Bootstrap template"src="'+picture+'" />'+'<div class="well"></div></div>');
 }
            },
               complete: function(){
    $('#loading-image').hide();
  },
            error: function (ErrorResponse) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(ErrorResponse));
            }
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

    }


    });  

    </script>
```

Comment: These links maybe helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495880/ajax-post-readystate0-responsetext-status0-statustexterror http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the PHP version on the server, when I changed the server with new PHP version, everything worked UP AND RUNNING!